# How to see transitive dependencies for mvnrepository.com?

Tags: maven, mvn-repo

Let's say I'm interested in using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.avro/avro. How can I find which other dependencies avro will bring in and which version of those dependencies it will bring in. I know I can manually add the dependency to a project's link pom.xml and run

```
mvn dependency:tree | tee tree.txt
```

to see which dependencies are used but this requires always fixing up compilation errors and there should be an easier way.

I was wondering if there's any way to check which transitive dependencies that a parent dependency will bring in using a website that will straight up mention that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://mvnrepository.com/ itself has the dependencies information just select a version and scroll down to see list of dependencies.

[image: Details]